# Why this layout dont align the content of textview vertically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Why this layout dont align the content of textview vertically?

I already tried change by code too and few another things in XML, but nothing solved my problem.

- The string in textView is temporary, I change this, after, from code.
- This layout is for an adapter for a ListView.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/item_lista_classe_personagem_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_margin="5dp" >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageCover"
      android:layout_width="70dp"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/sem_imagem" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageCover"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:text="@string/app_name"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:textColor="@color/Red" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Where I change string by code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(classePers.getNome());
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Comment: You could use a **compound drawable** and get rid of both the ImageView and the RelativeLayout container. Flatter designs are much better for performances.

Comment: How i change the size of the image in compound drawable?

Comment: By simply changing the height of the TextView.

Comment: But I have cases where the text is larger than the image, so I think the initial idea without compound drawable is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageView is inside your RelativeLayout.

Instead, replace the line

```
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

BY

```
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```